# Exception Spark sql code running on IntelliJ i.e java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: apache-spark

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",
              "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://127.0.0.1:9083")
      .master("local") //local
      .getOrCreate()
```

While running Spark SQL code in IntelliJ getting:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found`.

Comment: Are you asking a question?  If you are trying to solve this error, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you possibly missed the import (replace with spark version you're using):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or the following if using sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
```

Hope this helps !